# Tkinter text field with limited number of availabale character

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on an application to edit DNA sequences and I'd like to have a tkinter text widget in which only letters atgcATGC can be entered.

Is there any easy way to do that?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I really need a Text widget and not an Entry widget. Text widgets don't have validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a way to have the exact behavior I want:

```
from Tkinter import Text, BOTH
import re

class T(Text):

    def __init__(self, *a, **b):

        # Create self as a Text.
        Text.__init__(self, *a, **b)

        #self.bind("<Button-1>", self.click)
        self.bind("<Key>", self.key)
        self.bind("<Control-v>", self.paste)

    def key(self,k):
        if k.char and k.char not in "atgcATGC":
            return "break"

    def paste(self,event):
        clip=self.selection_get(selection='CLIPBOARD')
        clip=clip.replace("\n","").replace("\r","")
        m=re.match("[atgcATGC]*",clip)
        if m and m.group()==clip:
            self.clipboard_clear()
            self.clipboard_append(clip)
        else:
            self.clipboard_clear()
            return


t = T()
t.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
t.mainloop()
```

Comment: I really apreciate your code, it has really helped me out, but this way i m not able to use backspace either to delete characters.
Do you know how to add this option

Comment: actually I found out that I just needed to add "\b" to the filter string
Now it is working perfectly

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `validatecommand` feature of the `Entry` widget.  The best documentation I can find is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/python-tkinter-interactively-validating-entry-widget-content) to a similar question.  Following that example,

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MyApp():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        vcmd = (self.root.register(self.validate), '%S')
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.root, validate="key", 
                              validatecommand=vcmd)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def validate(self, S):

        return all(c in 'atgcATGC' for c in S)

app=MyApp()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I really need a Text widget and not an Entry widget. As far as I know Text widgets don't have validation.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to catch the `"<Key>"` event on the widget where you're entering text. Then you can just filter

```
if key.char and key.char not in "atgcATGC":
    return "break"
```

Here's some info on handling events in tkinter: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Comment: You don't _have_ to. That's one of at least a couple of solutions. Also, capturing `<Key>` won't handle pasting via the mouse (and as implemented won't handle pasting a string via shortcut). It's better to use the built-in input validation features of the widget -- this is exactly what they are for.

Comment: @Bryan: Oh yes, that is a better option. I didn't know about the validation features.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [Pmw](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/) toolkit which provides a lot of handy extras to Tkinter.  The Pmw [EntryField](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/EntryField.html) class allows you to write an arbitrary validator for any text field.  Pmw is lightweight and very usable, if you are developing anything in Tkinter you will probably find its features useful.